# PHP adding exact weekdays to a timestamp

Tags: php

I want to add an x number of week days  (e.g. 48 weekday hours) to the current timestamp. I am trying to do this using the following

```
echo (strtotime('2 weekdays');
```

However, this doesn't seem to take me an exact 48 hours ahead in time. For example, inputting the current server time of **Tuesday 18/03/2014 10:47** returns **Thursday 20/03/2014 00:00**. using the following function:

```
echo (strtotime('2 weekdays')-mktime())/86400;
```

It can tell that it's returning only **1.3 weekdays** from now.

Why is it doing this? Are there any existing functions which allow an exact amount of weekday hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want to preserve the `weekdays` functionality and not loose the hours, minutes and seconds, you could do this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$hms = new DateInterval(
    'PT'.$now->format('H').'H'.
    $now->format('i').'M'.
    $now->format('s').'S'.
);
$date = new DateTime('2 weekdays');
$date->add($hms);//add hours here again
```

The reason why `weekday` doesn't add the hours is because, if you add 1 weekday at any point in time on a monday, the next weekday *has* to be tuesday.
The hour simply *does not matter*. Say your date is `2014-01-02 12:12:12`, and you want the next weekday, that day starts at `2014-01-03 00:00:00`, so that's what you get.

My last solution works though, and here's how: I use the `$now` instance of `DateTime`, and its `format` method to construct a `DateInterval` format string, to be passed to the constructor. An interval format is quite easy: it starts with `P`, for period, then a digit and a char to indicate what that digit represents: 1Y for 1 Year, and 2D for 2 Days.
However, we're only interested in hours, minutes and seconds. Actual time, which is indicated using a `T` in the interval format string, hence we start the string with `PT` (Period Time).
Using the format specifiers `H`, `i` and `s`, we construct an interval format that in the case of 12:12:12 looks like this:

```
$hms = new DateInterval(
    'PT12H12M12S'
);
```

Then, it's a simple matter of calling the `DateTime::add` method to add the hours, minutes and seconds to our date + weekdays:

```
$weekdays = new DateTime('6 weekdays');
$weekdays->add($hms);
echo $weekdays->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
```

And you're there.
Alternatively, you could just use the basic same trick to compute the *actual* day-difference between your initial date, and that date + x weekdays, and then add that diff to your initial date. It's the same basic principle, but instead of having to create a format like `PTXHXMXS`, a simple `PXD` will do.

## [Working example here](http://ideone.com/0qNnHw)

I'd urge you to use the `DateInterface` classes, as it is more flexible, allows for type-hinting to be used and makes dealing with dates just a whole lot easier for all of us. Besides, it's not too different from your current code:

```
$today = new DateTime;
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$dayAfter = new DateTime('2 days');
```

In fact, it's a lot easier if you want to do frequent date manipulations on a single date:

```
$date = new DateTime();//or DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString);
$diff = new DateInterval('P2D');//2 days
$date->add($diff);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL, 'is the date + 2 days', PHP_EOL;
$date->sub($diff);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL, 'was the original date, now restored';
```

Easy, once you've spent some time browsing through [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: @emkay: I know why you're loosing the hours when using weekdays now, and I've added an (untested) approach to add them back on, too

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution. It's primitive but after some quick testing it seems to work.

The function calculates the time passed since midnight of the current day, and adds it onto the date returned by strtotime. Since this could fall into a weekend day, I've checked and added an extra day or two accordingly.

```
function weekDays($days)   {
    $tstamp = (strtotime($days.' weekdays') + (time() - strtotime("today")));
    if(date('D',$tstamp) == 'Sat')  {
        $tstamp = $tstamp + 86400*2;
    }
    elseif(date('D',$tstamp) == 'Sun')  {
        $tstamp = $tstamp + 86400;
    }

    return $tstamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `strtotime('2 weekdays')` seems to add 2 weekdays to the current date without the time.
If you want to add 48 hours why not adding 2*24*60*60 to mktime()?

```
echo(date('Y-m-d', mktime()+2*24*60*60));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this won't work because I want to retain the weekday functionality. I don't want weekends to be included.

Answer (score 0):

the modify in the php DateTime class works.

```
$start = new DateTime();
$start->modify('+ 2 weekdays');
```

Answer (score -1):

The currently accepted solution works, but it will fail when you want to add weekdays to a timestamp that is not now. Here's a simpler snippet that will work for any given point in time:

```
$start = new DateTime('2021-09-29 15:12:10');
$start->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('+ 3 weekdays'));
echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-10-04 15:12:10
```

Note that this will also work for a negative amount of weekdays:

```
$start = new DateTime('2021-09-29 15:12:10');
$start->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('- 3 weekdays'));
echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-09-24 15:12:10
```

Comment: in further researching your solution, the date_interval_from_create takes into account daylight savings time adjustments.  so losing/gaining an hour during those 2 weekends a year would also need to get addressed.